# Post increment C++ Output

Tags: c++, c++11, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=5, b;
    cout<<a++<<endl<<a++<<endl<<++a<<endl<<++a<<endl<<++a<<endl<<a++<<endl<<a++<<endl<<a++<<endl<<a++<<endl<<++a;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT: 14 13 15 15 15 9 8 7 6 15**

Can someone explain how the compiler got this output? I understood the pre-increment will be 15. But can someone explain how we're getting these post-increment values?

Comment: GCC warns that this operation invokes *undefined behavior*: https://godbolt.org/z/qiygDh

Comment: It's a classical undefined-behavior program that MSVC and GCC generate different outputs.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you really don't need all the extra stuff from all those `std::endl`s. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: but there might be some explanation for this undefined behavior?